# Elasticsearch 5 - Design approach for Many Small Sized but very different indices?

Tags: elasticsearch-5

With removal of 'type' in mapping from 5.x release, I have to have many indices need to be created. All Indices have documents which don't have many similarities.

For example,

Form of Application-1
Field - A (String)
Field - B (int)
Field - C (Date)

Form of Application - 2
Field - X (int)
Field - Y (int)
Field - Z (long)

There are as many as 50 Application per Tenant. It can scale up to 500 Tenant. So, Selected design approach can have 500 X 50 = 25000 Indices. However, Each indices/application might be very small memory size (i.e. KBs to Couple of MBs at Max)

I read the forum and it has been mostly suggested to keep dense data in minimum number of indices. But in my case, There are many models without no overlapping fields. So, I do see one option which is index per model (i.e. form of application in my use case)

My question : is it good design approach considering use case ? or better alternatives ?

Answer (score 0):

There's one solution to still have fake types and [Elastic team recommends](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html#_custom_type_field) that if number of documents per shard will be very small.

```
{
  "application1": {
    "a": "string",
    "b": "number",
    "c": "date"
  },
  "application2": {
    "x": "number",
    "y": "number",
    "z": "number"
}
```

So in this case `application1` and `application2` serve you as types.

Comment: But in that case, I'll have tons of Field in single index. So, For 50 application can have atleast 10-15 unique field each. Meaning, approximately, one index document will have 500-700 fields. One document instance will have only 10-15 data assigned and other will be just placeholder because of shared schema/mapping. Don't you think it's a problem of "Fields Bloating" ?

Comment: It is. This is rather a workaround to types removal. This is not ideal, but rather yet another solution that might work for you.

Comment: Another approach would be to create index per application and use tenant id as routing key.